# Get root container of an instrumented javafx application

Tags: javafx, agent

i have a JavaFx application, i want to load an agent into its virtual machine in order to get all UIControls.

The part where i load the agent will be done via [VirtualMachine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html)  but now i need a solution to get the root UI container.

I looked through the javadoc but i have not found anything which could help me achieving this. I made something similar in .NET with [Control.FromHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Is there a method in java which does the same? Or has somebody a few hints for me so i can focus on the right parts of the java api.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the `root` of the present `Scene` ?

Comment: If the present Scene is the root container then yes.

Comment: You can get the `scene` from the `stage` using `stage.getScene()`. From the scene, you can get the root by using `scene.getRoot()`

Comment: I believe [ScenicView][http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/] is able to determine the roots of JavaFX windows from JVM processes, though I have no idea what the actual mechanism it uses is, you could try asking the authors at http://fxexperience.com.